# Problem with Scrapy in yahoo finance site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having this problem with Scrapy, and I have no idea what it is.
Here is my Spider

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class YFScreener(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'YFScreener'
    allowed_domains = ['finance.yahoo.com']
    start_urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/c97bc7b4-0e94-43dc-9df1-b46f936742e6?count=25&offset=0']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/.*count=\d+&offset=\d+')), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        return response.css('tr.simpTblRow:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2)::text').get()
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/UQnSYarz) is the log that I get, and these are some of my settings:

```py
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
  'User Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'
}
```

I don't know what is happening, I used Scrappy before and I never had a problem. It seems to be something related to robots.txt, but I have no idea what that is. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running smoothly on my machine. I just refactor below function and turn on my ***vpn***

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        return {
            "url": response.css('tr.simpTblRow:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2)::text').get()
        }
```

Here is releted logs :

```
2020-07-07 08:41:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/c97bc7b4-0e94-43dc-9df1-b46f936742e6?count=25&offset=0> (referer: https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/c97bc7b4-0e94-43dc-9df1-b46f936742e6?count=25&offset=0)
2020-07-07 08:41:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/c97bc7b4-0e94-43dc-9df1-b46f936742e6?count=25&offset=0>
{'url': 'TYT.L'}
2020-07-07 08:41:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/c97bc7b4-0e94-43dc-9df1-b46f936742e6/heatmap?count=25&offset=0> (referer: https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/c97bc7b4-0e94-43dc-9df1-b46f936742e6?count=25&offset=0)
2020-07-07 08:41:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/c97bc7b4-0e94-43dc-9df1-b46f936742e6/heatmap?count=25&offset=0>
{'url': None}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it does not run on mine though. I don't think it is because of a VPN, given that I can access this page online via my browser. Also, it seems that I can wget the page, so I have no idea why Scrappy does not work here.

Comment: paste this line in settings.py `USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'` and replace with your user agent

Comment: this is my settings.py [link](https://i.ibb.co/nBMbGNV/Annotation-2020-07-11-185529.png)